# Get correct types for reusable function with different 'data' args object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function `getProperty` it will accept different kinds of args in my test case i have two different args `firstname` and `lastName`

In my `getProperty` function i have if statement that check which args are coming in and then returns that one.

From my understanding Generic is what i need to use but I'm getting error `Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'T'.`

How do i correctly type Generic for this to work?

```
type TdataV1 = {
  firstName: string
}

type TdataV2 = {
  lastName: string
}

const dataV1: TdataV1 = {
  firstName: 'Name',
}

const dataV2: TdataV2 = {
  lastName: 'Name',
}

const getProperty = <T>(data: T): string => {
  if (data.firstName) {
    return data.firstName
  }

  if (data.lastName) {
    return data.lastName
  }
}

getProperty<TdataV1>(dataV1)
getProperty<TdataV2>(dataV2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your types have an empty intersection (no common fields) so you should just write this:

```
const getProperty = (data: TdataV1 | TdataV2): string => {
  if ('firstName' in data) {
    return data.firstName
  }

  if ('lastName' in data) {
    return data.lastName
  }
}
```

TypeScript's [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator) will get you the correct type inside every `if` code block.

You can check this [playground demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgJgQ2AgagRigXigbwFBRQBmAlgE4DOwAcggLYQBcUVZJAdgOZ4C%20eeoSLETIUAJiy4CUADYIqtBs1YdufPAGMA9uypQRqNM3hJDk-IVKUa9JlADkiiPYA0vftt3B9p8cYPi5tJyCrbMjrau7po6epwQwAAKZFqQZKCSABQG-r4YAD7CvmIAlMrAbFxYAHxShCREUJn2VqEM9lAcPsgldYRQZAkArmTs3QgAdK02DNLq9Y3NITPOnWMGvRb9g8Aj66YTy05zvEA) too see it in action.

Comment: i'm trying to avoid this because i could have a lot of this reusable function that obj will be different and i don't want to type all those object in when i know TS inherits them, so i just want to re-use what ts gets from plain objects and pass those types automatically to function

Comment: OK then take a look at the other answer it might suit your needs

Comment: Just a minor note: This code has a slightly different effect from the example. `'firstName' in data` returns true if `data` has a `firstName` property, even if `data.firstName` is falsy. The OP's version requires `data.firstName` to be truthy. This might be better or worse depending on the OP's use case.

Comment: @JustinMorgan indeed I assumed than OP needed property existence

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like following: with another arg in your function to add more type protection
cf. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html

```
type TdataV1 = {
  firstName: string;
};

type TdataV2 = {
  lastName: string;
};

const dataV1: TdataV1 = {
  firstName: 'Name',
};

const dataV2: TdataV2 = {
  lastName: 'Name',
};

const getKeyProperty = <T>(data: T, key: keyof T) => {
  if (data[key]) return data[key];
};

getKeyProperty<TdataV1>(dataV1, 'firstName');
getKeyProperty<TdataV2>(dataV2, 'lastName');
```

Comment: The type can be inferred from the parameters in the function calls, no need to specify it between "inferior" and "superior" characters

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you don't want to list out all the possible types, it seems like generics aren't necessary for this. You can just do something like this:

```
const getProperty = (data: { [key: string]: string }): string => {
  if (data.firstName) {
    return data.firstName
  }

  if (data.lastName) {
    return data.lastName
  }
}
```